# Spyder variable explorer duplicate

Tags: python, spyder, anaconda3

when Start new project in spyder and set file working directory and set new variables it's duplicate the variables by adding new variables and variables from previous projects such this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Mwv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you need to go the IPython console in the Spyder IDE and type %reset before start running things.

Comment: when I type %reset in IPython console it remove all variables and when set new variables again  it's appear with also the previous variables also